# Mark Jenkins node as in use externally

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have a cluster of a few machines, some of these machines are used as a compute cluster and some are used with Jenkins for CI. This is usually fine since there's a lot of downtime on the machines, but if the Jenkins pipeline is run at the same time it causes timeouts to kick in because the code takes too long to run.

Is there a way I can notify Jenkins that the node is in use without having to go through the UI (and reverse the action)?

Is there a way to set a lock file or an equivalent (this could be more robust if there are more than 2 things using the machines)?

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins [Lockable Resources](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources) plugin could be useful for your particular issue.

Integrated with Pipeline jobs also.

Comment: This seems reasonable, but it makes the resource dependent on Jenkins since the lock is held by Jenkins. It would be much more preferable if Jenkins would ask for the lock instead, since that way the resource wouldn't become inaccessible if Jenkins is down for some reason or the other.